Help me unlock an old laptop

My nerdy roommate has some really important notes for an upcoming exam and he won't give them to me! So I stole his laptop and now I need to find the password, which is why I'm here. I think you'll find everything you need here. Maybe what I did was unethical, but I NEED THOSE FILES.
The story is fake btw.

Out of interest, why the repost? (10k user link to deleted question) Thanks.

Evolution; weak organisms get wiped out and the stronger ones live long enough to reproduce.

Let me try again:

 The password is 0577

Lorenzo and pasta:

 With the flavor text of an intellectual individual being your friend points to the famous mathematician Lorenzo Mascheroni (a wordplay on ‘macaroni’).


 The bottom row of the background has the letters C,O,Y these are all notations of the Euler–Mascheroni constant.


 The **** and numpad points to the password being 4 digits long and so with all the clues in place what could the answer be other that first four digits of the constant: 0577…


Good work PDT (Persistent, Determined, Thoughtful)

It was actually prince deep thinker but I like your interpretation!
